# Why are agenda and tag shortcuts for org-mode not working?

Tags: org-mode

I am relatively new to Emacs and was going through this document to learn more about org-mode: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html

I couldn't help but notice that the following shortcuts were not working:

- > `C-c / t` – show TODOs in current document

  - My emacs frame says `C-c t is undefined`
- > Imagine that you have a large document, with scattered all over the document TODO entries, `C-c C-v` will show only your current TODOs, and folding the rest away.

  - My emacs frame says `C-c C-v-` is displayed in echo area, as if it is awaiting another keystoke (? Control sequence?)
- > Unfortunately, both will show just empty lists (you can try if you want). So just press C-g (the Emacs version of escape). Next we will add 1.org as agenda file, using C-c [. Now if you go to the agenda menu (`C-c a`), and press `t` you get a list off all your TODO items.

  - In my emacs frame, although `C-c [` does add the file to the list of agendas, the `C-c a` shortcut says `C-c a is undefined` in the echo area. Obviously the `t` keystroke does nothing as well in this case.

What can I do to solve my problems? I installed Emacs using [these instructions](https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl) and I am using WSL2 on Windows with the Ubuntu-20.04 distro. I followed the instructions exactly in the tutorial.

Here is my `~/.emacs` file if it is necessary:

```lisp
;; -*- mode: elisp -*-

;; Disable the splash screen (to enable it agin, replace the t with 0)
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;; Enable transient mark mode
(transient-mark-mode 1)

;;;;Org mode configuration
;; Enable Org mode
(require 'org)
;; Make Org mode work with files ending in .org
;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
;; The above is the default in recent emacsen
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-agenda-files '("~/test/emacs/1.org" "~/test/emacs/2.org")))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: Those keybindings are only defined in Org mode, not everywhere: you need to be  *in* an Org mode document. When you visit a file, e.g. `foo.org`, make sure that the mode line says `(Org)` - if that's the case, then `C-c / t` et al. should work. `C-c C-v` however is *not* defined anywhere that I can find, so it may be that that tutorial is outdated.

Comment: For `C-c a`, that is a *suggested* keybinding and you have to do that for yourself: it is not done by Org mode. See [Activation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: @NickD Yes, I am in org mode (the mode line says `(Org)`). Everything else is working fine except these. Maybe I am misinterpreting the `C-c / t` thing.. Ah! This does actually mean you have to press the `/` key between the `C-c` and `t`, I thought that was perhaps a typo. OK ya, most of it seems to work now. Is there an equivalent to `C-c C-v` in what is Org mode today?

Comment: `C-c C-v` is a prefix indeed. Do `C-h m` in an Org mode buffer and explore!